# What is the error in making trigger in this?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I made a trigger like this:

```
create trigger mytrigger 
before 
insert on
person4
for each row
begin
if new.salary < 5000 then
    set new.salary = 6000;
end if;
end;
```

Here salary is an attribute of the table person4 and I am making a trigger for this. However, it shows the error: `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 8`

Why is this happeneing? The syntax is complete correct. Why then is it happeneing?

Comment: Look like you are missing the delimiter. At the beginning `delimiter //` and finally `end;//`

Comment: Did this: `delimiter //
create trigger mytrigger 
before 
insert on
person4
for each row
begin
if new.salary < 5000 then
    set new.salary = 6000;
end if;
end;//` But still shows the error.

Comment: You should also restore delimiter at the end like: delimiter ;

Comment: How? Can you please write a seperate answer because I am already getting a syntax error and like this, I am not able to figure it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trigger looks good the only thing missing was the delimiter.

I just created a triger with sample table and here it is

```
delimiter //
create trigger mytrigger before insert on person4
for each row
begin
 if new.salary < 5000 then
   set new.salary = 6000;
 end if;
end;//

delimiter;
```

Here is the mysql test

```
mysql> create table person4(id int, name varchar(20),salary int);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.16 sec)

mysql> insert into person4 values (1,'aa',6000);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.06 sec)
mysql> select * from person4;
+------+------+--------+
| id   | name | salary |
+------+------+--------+
|    1 | aa   |   6000 |
+------+------+--------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> insert into person4 values (1,'bb','3000');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.04 sec)

mysql> select * from person4;
+------+------+--------+
| id   | name | salary |
+------+------+--------+
|    1 | aa   |   6000 |
|    1 | bb   |   6000 |
+------+------+--------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: I just executed the query you wrote and it shows the following error: `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'delimiter' at line 1 `.

Comment: are you executing on mysql terminal ?

Comment: I am executing on xampp using phpmyadmin.

Comment: weird in phpmyadmin it should work. May be this could help you to create trigger on phpmyadmin client http://phpsblog.agustinvillalba.com/create-triggers-phpmyadmin/